# Change from pull image to local build when run skaffold dev

Tags: docker, kubernetes, continuous-deployment, skaffold, k3d

I'm trying to create a local development environment with Skaffold and k3d.

My environment consists of multiple Skaffold modules and every modules declares a dev profile. The main `skaffold.yaml` consists of multiple requires statement that are pointing to multiple git repos (every repo has its own skaffold configuration).

In order to prepare the cluster, when I create a cluster using k3d, I run `skaffold run -p dev`.

Every skaffold modules declare a profile like this:

```yaml
profiles:
  - name: dev
    build:
      local:
        push: false
        useDockerCLI: false
      artifacts:
        - image: my-org/my-image
          docker: {}
          sync:
            infer:
              - '**/*.ts'
```

This profile is useful if I want to develop on a particular module, but when i want to setup the entire cluster, skaffold will build all the images instead of pulling them from a repo.

What I want to achieve is to build locally when I want to run `skaffold dev` on a particular module, but pull images when i run `skaffold run` against my `skaffold.yaml` entry point.

Is is possibile to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> What I want to achieve is to build locally when I want to run `skaffold dev` on a particular module, but pull images when I run `skaffold run` against my `skaffold.yaml` entry point.

Using [Skaffold profile](https://skaffold.dev/docs/environment/profiles/), as you do in your question for local development, is a good idea, but you could also introduce an *additional* profile specifically for pulling images from a repository when running the main `skaffold.yaml`.

You would have:

- your existing `dev` profile in each module, configured for local development, allowing local builds with specific settings like `push: false`. It is ideal for working on individual modules.
- a new profile for pulling images (`pull-images` Profile), introduced to handle the specific case where you want to pull images from a repository instead of building them locally. That profile should be defined in each module's `skaffold.yaml`.

The main `skaffold.yaml` uses [`requires` statements](https://skaffold.dev/docs/design/config/#requires-statement) to include all modules.
By specifying the `pull-images` profile when running `skaffold run -p pull-images`, it tells Skaffold to use the `pull-images` profile for each module. That results in pulling images for the entire cluster setup instead of building them.

That would allow you to distinguish between two scenarios:

- local development (`skaffold dev`): use the `dev` profile for building images locally when working on individual modules.
- cluster setup (`skaffold run`): use the `pull-images` profile to pull images from a repository for all modules when setting up the entire cluster.

```bash
┌──────────────────────────────┐   ┌──────────────────────────────┐
│ Individual Module Development│   │        Cluster Setup         │
└──────────────────────────────┘   └──────────────────────────────┘
            │                                        │            
            │                                        │            
            ▼                                        ▼            
┌──────────────────────────────┐   ┌──────────────────────────────┐
│       skaffold dev           │   │ skaffold run -p pull-images  │
└──────────────────────────────┘   └──────────────────────────────┘
            │                                        │            
            │                                        │            
            ▼                                        ▼            
┌──────────────────────────────┐   ┌──────────────────────────────┐
│          dev profile         │   │       pull-images profile    │
│      (Build Locally)         │   │    (Pull from Repository)    │
└──────────────────────────────┘   └──────────────────────────────┘
```

Your module Skaffold configuration would be:

```yaml
profiles:
  - name: dev
    # Your existing dev profile configuration
  - name: pull-images
    build:
      artifacts:
        - image: my-org/my-image
          docker:
            buildArgs:
              PULL_IMAGE: "true"
```

And in your main `skaffold.yaml`:

```yaml
requires:
  - path: ./path-to-module
    profiles: [pull-images]
```

Applying these changes to your example module's `skaffold.yaml`:

```yaml
profiles:
  - name: dev
    build:
      local:
        push: false
        useDockerCLI: false
      artifacts:
        - image: my-org/my-image
          docker: {}
          sync:
            infer:
              - '**/*.ts'
  - name: pull-images
    build:
      artifacts:
        - image: my-org/my-image
          docker:
            buildArgs:
              PULL_IMAGE: "true"
```